# Docker.Dotnet How to pull an Image

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I want to pull and run an Image with [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/microsoft/Docker.DotNet) and I am desperated, I have no Idea how to do this with this library.

Can anyone help me?

I looked at the tutorial on the https://github.com/microsoft/Docker.DotNet but that is not helpful.

```
 public class DockerService
    {
        private readonly DockerClient DockerClient;

        public DockerService()
        {
            if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
            {
                DockerClient = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("npipe://./pipe/docker_engine")).CreateClient();
            }
            else if (OperatingSystem.IsLinux())
            {
                DockerClient = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("unix:///var/run/docker.sock")).CreateClient();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("unknown operation system");
            }
        }

        public void StartCompose()
        {
            var progress = new Progress<JSONMessage>();
            var task = PullImage(
                new ImagesCreateParameters()
                {
                    FromImage = "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk",
                    Tag = "latest"
                },null,
                progress);
             task.Wait();

        }


        private Task PullImage(ImagesCreateParameters imagesCreateParameters, AuthConfig authConfig,
            Progress<JSONMessage> progress)
        {
            return DockerClient.Images.CreateImageAsync(imagesCreateParameters, authConfig, progress);
        }

    }
```

I expect something to happen when I start task.wait()? But the it runs for several minutes and nothing happens.

Comment: If only the documentation at https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet#example-create-an-image-by-pulling-from-docker-registry was as good as this article....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code downloads the image and adds it to your local Docker registry. Run the command `docker images` from the command line and you should see that the image is there now.

Comment: Yes you are right. Yesterday I reinstalled docker and after that it works and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Your image name looks wrong. You have the repository, but not the tag.

Looking at: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk/

suggests you need: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2`

Comment: But that did not change anything. I add latest but the task is runing and runnig and nothing happens.

Comment: @ChristianSchulze have you checked you can docker pull this image from the command line?